# Simple powershell upload to GCP bucket

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform

I have a test bucket that is publicly available, and I use a simple .ps1 file to download files from it.

I'm trying to do the reverse, upload a txt file, but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to do this without installing the gcloud cmdlets b/c I want this to work on any machine.

```
$destination = "https://storage.googleapis.com/somerandombucket/test.txt"
$source = "test.txt"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UploadFile($source, $destination)
```

Is this possible? I'm open to passing credentials, but my hope is to not have to download the gcloud cmdlets, as I didn't them for the download via url. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the powershell failure notice:

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception
>   occurred during a WebClient request." At C:\xxxxxxxxx\testupload.ps1:6
>   char:1
>   + $wc.UploadFile($source, $destination)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to **download** and **upload** an object from and to an public Google Cloud Storage bucket:

1. Give the bucket **Storage Object Viewer** (for downloading the objects) and **Storage Object Creator** (for uploading to the bucket) permissions and assign them to "allUsers". `NOTE: This will make the bucket public and anyone from the internet will be able to upload objects and download them.`
2. Use this `upload.ps1` PowerShell file to upload an object

```
#Upload file to Google Cloud Storage
$dir = "C:\PATH\TO\OBJECT\image.jpg"
$bucket_name = "[BUCKET_NAME]"
$Uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/$bucket_name/o?uploadType=media&name=image.jpg"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Uri -Header $header -ContentType "image/jpg" -InFile "$dir"
```

1. Use this `download.ps1` PowerShell file to download an object

```
#Download from Google Cloud Storage
$bucket_name = "[BUCKET_NAME]"
$bucket_file = "https://storage.googleapis.com/$bucket_name/image.jpg"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$bucket_file" -Method Get -OutFile C:image.jpg
```

I have tested the method above and I can confirm to you that I was able to download and upload an object successfully, using the PowerShell scripts above.